# How to apply automatic scrolling on Listview on Page Load in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to apply automatic scrolling to this ListTile,

```
  Container(
                      height: 70,
                      width: double.maxFinite,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        controller: _controller,
                        key: itemKey,
                        itemCount: 10,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return ListTile(
                            title: Text('demo ${index + 1}'),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
```

I declared this

```
  final itemKey = GlobalKey();
  final _controller = ScrollController();
```

And I placed this after widget build...

```
  if (_controller.hasClients) {
      _controller.animateTo(_controller.position.maxScrollExtent,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.easeInOut);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can animate the list after first frame is build using `addPostFrameCallback`

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      if (_controller.hasClients) {
        _controller.animateTo(_controller.position.maxScrollExtent,
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            curve: Curves.easeInOut);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: It works but faced issue. How can I wrap it to StreamBuilder. I tried but no longer scrolling

Comment: still accepting help

Comment: Stream builder takes more than 1 frame to fetch data, that's why it wont scroll while using it on initState