# How to add automatic scroll to a StreamBuilder Listview in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, listview, scroll

[I asked this question and got the accurate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74090927/how-to-apply-automatic-scrolling-on-listview-on-page-load-in-flutter/74090934#74090934)

It worked fine, then I tried wrapping it to **StreamBuilder** as seen below, it stopped working

```
StreamBuilder<List<WinsModel>>(
                              stream: WinController().readWins(),
                              builder: (context, snapshot2) {
                                if (snapshot2.hasError) {
                                  return NoData(
                                      text: "Error: 947474774", title: "");
                                } else if (snapshot2.hasData) {
                                  final testi = snapshot2.data!;
                                  return ListView.builder(
                                    controller: _controller,
                                    key: itemKey,
                                    itemCount: testi.length,
                                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                                      return ListTile(
                                        title: SmallText(
                                          text: testi[index].body,
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          size: FDiamension.getSize(16),
                                          isBold: true,
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    },
                                  );
                                } else {
                                  return Container();
                                }
                              }),
```

Please which way to add automatic scroll to a StreamBuilder Listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      if (_controller.hasClients) {
        _controller.animateTo(_controller.position.maxScrollExtent,
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            curve: Curves.easeInOut);
      }
    });
```

after

**} else if (snapshot2.hasData) {**

Like

```
StreamBuilder<List<WinsModel>>(
                              stream: WinController().readWins(),
                              builder: (context, snapshot2) {
                                if (snapshot2.hasError) {
                                  return NoData(
                                      text: "Error: 947474774", title: "");
                                } else if (snapshot2.hasData) {

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
          if (_controller.hasClients) {
            _controller.animateTo(_controller.position.maxScrollExtent,
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                curve: Curves.easeInOut);
          }
        });
                                  final testi = snapshot2.data!;
                                  return ListView.builder(
                                    controller: _controller,
                                    key: itemKey,
                                    itemCount: testi.length,
                                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                                      return ListTile(
                                        title: SmallText(
                                          text: testi[index].body,
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          size: FDiamension.getSize(16),
                                          isBold: true,
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    },
                                  );
                                } else {
                                  return Container();
                                }
                              }),
```